# common multiple polynominal time

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Given $n$ rational numbers.

Is there a polynominal time algorithm to compute a common denominator?

My idea was for each number search for $k_i$ so that $k_i \cdot n_i$ is integer.

Then the solution is $k_1 \cdot ... \cdot k_n$, but I don't think that this product stays polynominal in size?

Comment: What is a common multiple of two real numbers? Or, as an alternative phrasing, why is $1$ not always a solution?

Comment: What kind of real numbers are you dealing with? FOr example, if you have $1, \sqrt{2}$ there is no way on finding a common multiple.

Comment: oh sorry i meant rational number. a common multiple (i am not sure if it is called common multiple for rational numbers too) is a number so that k * n_i is integer for all n_i

Comment: This is a common denominator, isn't it ?

Comment: Are your rational numbers of the form $a/b$ with $a,b$ coprime integers, or are they expressed in binary expansion?

Comment: oh yes it was a translation mistake it is called common denominator. The rational numbers are expressed as finite decimal numbers, i.e. 1.20394

Comment: If you type $$\rm algorithm\ to\ compute\ a\ common\ multiple$$ into Google you will find some items of interest.

Comment: Then all denominators are powers of 10 !? (possibly even every time the same !!)

Comment: yes you can than take the biggest power of 10. easy thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you know Euclid's Algorithm?  Given two numbers $a,b$, it finds the greatest common factor $d$.  The least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is $ab/d$.

Start with $C=n_1$.  For each $n_i$, starting at $n_2$, replace $C$ by the least common multiple of $C$ and $n_i$.  The final value of $C$ is the least common multiple of all the $n_i$.

"polynomial time" in this case, means polynomial in the number of digits.  The number of digits in the Least Common Multiple is at most the sum of the number of digits in all the $n_i$.  The sum is a linear polynomial, so this is polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

In case all the denominators are distinct primes, you can't avoid the full product, which indeed has an exponential size.

For the $lcm$ (least common multiple), use the Euclidean algorithm and the property $lcm(a,b)\cdot gcd(a,b)=a\cdot b$.